# Kernel Panic on Hibernate / after unplugging Devices

Tags: sleep-wake, kernel-panic

When I'm at work, I've got my Macbook connected to an external monitor and a Apple Magic Mouse + Apple keyboard (both bluetooth) and I am connected via ethernet.

When I unplug all devices and take my Macbook back home after work it normally goes to sleep mode and when I open it afterwards I get back right to where I left.
Recently I experience a lot of kernel panics when I am back at home (not every time). The white light doesn't flash anymore and when I open it, it tells me something went wrong and the system had to be shut down. Always showing this Log:

https://gist.github.com/martinhelfert/9531915

Any idea whats causing this? Checked RAM with memtest, sending it to sleep mode before disconnecting, checked the hard disk for errors, did the smc reset already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magical word in your question is: "Sometimes"

The only error in your log has to do with the IO (Input Output).

Pay attention if your are sometimes in a hurry and jerk those connections cables out and slam the lid.

sometimes the problem is solved if you just give it a bit time to sort things out = Wait a bit!

the system has to create a large file-sleep image and since you pulled all the plugs some of the apps have not reported they state before sleep image is done.

Try the routine of unplug count to 3, unplug next one ect.

Comment: The lid is acutally never opened ;) It's just connected with the external monitor. But it seems time really was the problem here. I now open the lid, disconnect all cables, wait some time and then close the lid. Never had this problem again since then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a fresh, new user account and seeing if the problem persists there? It could be due to something your user account is loading or running in the background.